# Is it normal for a boat to break after like 5 blocks travel distance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

With the newest patch released, I created a new world and spawned on a very, very small Island. So I made a wooden Boat. But it keeps breaking after a few Blocks of travel distance. Is this normal?

I am on Singleplayer normal mode.

Comment: I don't know if this matters but boats break upon hitting Lilly pads now. You may be running into them without taking notice.

Comment: 1 block deep water is enough to break it if you're going at full speed

Comment: @IlayaRajaS No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.** Unfortunately, for some reason, in 1.7.2, the boats seem more prone to breaking than they had in previous updates (though on par with early updates).

This has been fixed in the 1.9 update. Boats are now rather durable, and will not break with even a fast impact.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta I don't know what to tell you. Like I said, I have a *hunch* that it'll be fixed, but it's not a bug, and it's not just you. Go poke Dinnerbone on Twitter, or something.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta: No need to get angry about it - just start a new world. Alternately, there's nothing stopping you from swimming away.

Comment: Odd, I've had no trouble with boats. I had a boat from a snapshot that got me all around the islands in 1.7.2, and when that broke (legit: I ran into the shore), the replacement I made has been going strong too. There must be something more nuanced happening.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Perhaps... I'll get some testing going later, I guess.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta, Comments are flagged and removed pretty frequently, they're intended for specific purposes as outlined [in the privileges section](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for commenting.  If you've got a question or issue with the community or site policies, it's better to [bring it up on meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/).