# Does this dock work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have designed a dock in which you have a water stream preventing the boat from going out of my desired perimeter.

[image]

What I did was make a wall with a 3 block wide opening facing the water. Then place sign boards on either side so that there is no water stream towards the ocean or my dock.

[image]
Here and there. After that all I had to do was put water both sides and the stream facing each other.
At last cover it all up like that.
[image]

I did some testing but I would like you guys to test it out too and answer if there are any problems.

Comment: Some daytime screenshots would be beneficial.

Comment: @biff Yeah I'll do that soon I thought night looked good on that.

Comment: "I did some testing but I would like you guys to test it out too and point if there are any problems." I'm not quite sure if our QA-site is well suited for this kind of request... Say someone posts an answer of any kind. How do the users go about up- or downvoting the answer?

Comment: @DJ Pirtu if someone post an answer I expect it to be a short coming in my design. If others think it's true upvote. If it's a myth then down vote. So it will work. If it goes unanswered I will assume it works! Simple

Comment: This seems more like an answer than a question.

Comment: @ChargingPun sorry for that but I couldn't go about asking for dock designs if I have one right.

Comment: In reply to the question being too broad I think it isn't because I have got the answer from Unionhawk. He has clearly stated what features my dock has and what doesn't. In two paragraphs!

Comment: Actually you can. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer That's how Q and A works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work... Well, I'll leave that up to you to decide. It does seem that it does hold a boat. So in that sense it does work. Hooray!

However, [boats are finicky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137822/is-it-normal-for-a-boat-to-break-after-like-5-blocks-travel-distance/137823#137823). Still. So there's a good chance that you'll end up just crashing it anyway. Since you get a whole boat back when you punch it, just breaking your boat and leaving it in a chest is probably a better option than crashing it into a wall anyway.

Comment: True, but when I jump off it just goes too far that's why I did this to give a easy and simple commute. I'm too lazy to hit jump after shift key. :-P